# SQL to LINQ: using group by, join, where with count

Tags: sql-server, linq, join, group-by

I have SQL like this:

```
select p.ProductID, count(pa.Value) as condition
from ProductBE as p
join ProductAttributeBE as pa 
on p.ProductID = pa.ProductID
where ProductCategoryID = 1203
and (Value = 'PassingerCar' or Value = '15')
group by p.ProductID
```

ProductBE is one to more with ProductAttributeBE
What think it seams to be like this:

```
var query1 = from p in this.DataBase.ProductBEs
             join a in this.DataBase.ProductAttributeBEs
             on p.ProductID equals a.ProductID
             where  p.ProductCategoryID == 1203 && (a.Value == radius ||                    a.Value == carType) 
             group p by p.ProductID into grp
             select new { grp.Key, Condition = grp.Count(x => x.Value !=   null) };
```

This code doesn't compiled
Have problem with selecting or grouping from different tables/allias

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var query1 = from p in this.DataBase.ProductBEs
             join a in this.DataBase.ProductAttributeBEs
             on p.ProductID equals a.ProductID
             where  p.ProductCategoryID == 1203 && (a.Value == radius || a.Value == carType) 
             select new {p.ProductID, a.Value} into t
             group t by t.ProductID into grp
             select new { grp.Key, Condition = grp.Count(x => x.Value != null) };
```